# How to increase or decrease the tag value in C#?

Tags: c#

I have dynamically added controls to my flowLayoutPanel and I'm offering the user to choose which pair of label and richTextBox does he wants to delete (label text is simply 1.,2.,3.,...) and tags are just numbers(1,2,3,...). This is how I did deleting the controls:

```
pairToDelete = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
foreach (Control ctrl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    if (ctrl.Tag.ToString() == pairToDelete.ToString())
    {
         Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        ctrl.Dispose();
    }
}

foreach (Control ctrl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
{
    if (ctrl.Tag.ToString() == pairToDelete.ToString())
    {
        Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        ctrl.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now, what I want is to change the tags of next pairs of controls. For example, if the user wants to delete 2nd pair of label and RTBox then I want to change tags of label3 and RTBox3 from 3 to 2, tags of label4 and RTBox4 from 4 to 3 etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Which part do you have a difficulty with? What have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you just do it ?(by bearing in mind that `Tag` is an object and, consequently, you will have to perform some conversion/cast to numeric type). That is: create a function going through all the controls and updating the values. On the other hand, the first question coming to my mind is why do you want to do such a thing? Why not keeping always the same values? At the start you have 1, 2, 3 and suddently 2 is deleted; what is the problem with that? It might be a problem in case of dealing with very big amounts of numbers, what doesn't seem the case here.

Comment: @varocarbas I was thinking about the same line, but then it occured to me that perhaps he has the number in the label text and use it as a way to let the user choose the pair to delete.

Comment: Pretty sure that you have nailed everything here. :-)

Comment: @Steve. All clear. I will better write an answer with my impressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified a little bit the mechanism to find a control to remove. After that I removing the control the way you remove it. After that I'm lowering the tag number of any control that has the tag higher then the removed control. Assumption is that the tags are numbers. I leave for you to do appropriate checks.

```
public void Delete()
{
    var pairToDelete = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    // Find what to remove.
    var lblToDelete = this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
            .FirstOrDefault(l => l.Tag.ToString() == pairToDelete.ToString());
    var txtToDelete = this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Tag.ToString() == pairToDelete.ToString());

    // Can be removed?
    if (lblToDelete != null)
    {
        // Remove.
        this.Controls.Remove(lblToDelete);
        lblToDelete.Dispose();

        // Lower tag number for labels with tag higher then the removed one.
        foreach (var c in this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
            .Where(l => Convert.ToInt32(l.Tag) > pairToDelete))
        {
            var newTag = Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag) - 1;
            c.Tag = newTag;
        }
    }

    // Can be removed?
    if (txtToDelete != null)
    {
        // Remove.
        this.Controls.Remove(txtToDelete);
        txtToDelete.Dispose();

        // Lower tag number for rich textvbox with tag higher then the removed one.
        foreach (var c in this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>()
                .Where(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Tag) > pairToDelete))
            {
                var newTag = Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag) - 1;
                c.Tag = newTag;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct but that ForEach after the ToList is horrible, a normal foreach is preferable here (in my opinion)

Comment: Fair enough. That's just my unhealthy bias toward oneliners. I'll add a version done in a standard way as well.

Comment: Yes, sometime I wonder about the usefulness of ForEach See: [foreach vs ForEach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Comment: Worth having a read. I just liked "this trivial one-liner"... But being more serious I think applying the standard `foreach` actually makes the whole method more readable. Though the `ForEach` keeps it consistant with the whole Linq query concept.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me.

Answer (score 2):

In these situations where different controls are related, I prefer to rely on an additional storage (on top of the `Controls` collection) to ease all the actions among controls. For example, a class like the following one:

```
public class LabelRTB
{
    public Label label;
    public RichTextBox rtb;

    public LabelRTB(Label label_arg, RichTextBox rtb_arg)
    {
        label = label_arg;
        rtb = rtb_arg;
    }
}
```

It can be populated on form load:

```
List<LabelRTB> allLabelRTB = new List<LabelRTB>();
allLabelRTB.Add(new LabelRTB(label1, rtb1));
allLabelRTB.Add(new LabelRTB(label2, rtb2));

this.Tag = allLabelRTB;
```

The requested deletion is now straightforward and the indices are updated automatically. For example:

```
private void removeItem(int index)
{
    LabelRTB curItem = ((List<LabelRTB>)this.Tag)[index];

    Controls.Remove(curItem.label);
    Controls.Remove(curItem.rtb);

    ((List<LabelRTB>)this.Tag).Remove(curItem);
}
```

As far as the number of controls is quite limited and the complexity of the associated actions might be reduced notably, this a-priori-less-efficient approach (it stores the same information twice) might even make the application more efficient than in case of exclusively relying on `Controls`.

Answer (score 0):

This is also one of the solutions:

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
 {
        if (ctrl.Tag.ToString() == pairToDelete.ToString())
        {
               Controls.Remove(ctrl);
               ctrl.Dispose();
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ctrl.Tag) > pairToDelete)
        {
               int decrease = Convert.ToInt32(ctrl.Tag) - 1;
               ctrl.Tag = decrease;

               ctrl.Text = decrease + ".";
        }
 }

 foreach (Control ctrl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
 {
        if (ctrl.Tag.ToString() == pairToDelete.ToString())
        {
               Controls.Remove(ctrl);
               ctrl.Dispose();
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ctrl.Tag) > pairToDelete)
        {
               int decrease = Convert.ToInt32(ctrl.Tag) - 1;
               ctrl.Tag = decrease;
        }
 }
```